# How to use ReactTable with useQuery?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, react-table

Except 'ReactTable...', code is running perfectly, when i add ReactTable screen become blank white and popup below error on console

> Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.

Here is the code. {data.searches} contains the query data. When i use {JSON.stringify(data.searches)} it returns string but when i use {data.searches} or  {[data.searches]} in ReactTable it shows above error.

MobileInfo.js

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import ReactTable from 'react-table'
//import 'react-table/react-table.css'
import gql from "graphql-tag"
import {Query} from 'react-apollo'
import {useQuery} from 'react-apollo'
import Error from './Forms/Errors'
import Loading from './Forms/Loading'

const LIST_INFO= gql`

query searches ($search:String!)
{
    searches(search:$search)
      {
      name  
        Launch
        Display
        Color
        Memory  
    }
  }
`

const Search=()=>{

       const clickHandler= async ()=>{
        setSearch(sSearch);
        console.log(data.searches);
        content=data.searches;

       };        
        const [search, setSearch]= useState('') 
        const {data, loading, error}=useQuery(LIST_INFO, {
            variables: { search }
        });

        let sSearch;
        let content;
            if (loading) return <Loading/>;
            if (error) return <Error error={error}/>;
            const mobile = data.searches;
           // content = ` info: ${mobile.name} Launch: ${mobile.Launch}`
           const columns = [
            {
                Header: "LAUNCH",
                accessor: "Launch"
            },
            {
                Header: "NAME",
                accessor: "name"
            },
            {
                Header: "DISPLAY",
                accessor: "Display"
            },
            {
                Header: "COLOR",
                accessor: "Color"
            },
            {
                Header: "MEMORY",
                accessor: "Memory"
            }
        ]
        return (
            
            <div>
                     
              <input type="text" onChange={ (e) => {sSearch=e.target.value}}/>
             <button onClick={clickHandler} value={search} >
               Search
                </button> 
                <div><p>{JSON.stringify(data.searches)}</p></div>
                <ReactTable data={data.searches} columns={ columns } />  
            
            </div>
            )
        };
export default Search;
```

Comment: `useLazyQuery` .

Comment: After replacing useQuery with useLazyQuery :TypeError: Cannot read property 'searches' of undefined

Comment: normal in react when data not ready/loaded

Comment: Its not executing, than is there any way that i put <ReactTable../> in async ClickHandler? this may resolve my hurdle

Comment: if no data then don't render table? just conditional rendering

Comment: ... and of course you can't render nor return component from handler .... I don't know what `cont mobile...` is for (it fails, too) .... `earlier rendering was blocked by `loading`, not sufficient now

Comment: I use "const mobile" for replacement of "data.searches". but this one also of no use.

Comment: `data` can be undefined during 1st render, any access to data's properties fails at this moment

Comment: `<button onClick={(event) => {
                event.preventDefault();
                setSearch(sSearch); 
                runQuery({
                 variables: { search }, // note: name = property shorthand
                 suspend: false
                })}}
                 value={search} >
                Search
                </button>`,**i tried this for lazyQuery  same error data.searches not working, that also giving error of undefined**

Comment: how did you "if no data then don't render table? just conditional rendering" ? ... before any other required changes (event handler)

Comment: no, this is about button, completely different thing

Comment: than how to tackle 1st render? as we cant access `data` here? call `data.searches` somewhere else?

Comment: not use it at this moment, not render react table component - render it conditionally ... "react conditional rendering"

Comment: @xadm i tried but still stuck on this point, sorry for your time, can u plz code it, so i can get rid of this error

Comment: eh... `{data && <ReactTable `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to replace `import ReactTable from 'react-table'` with `import ReactTable from "react-table-6"`. For me now its working fine, It may help some one.